# How to send an HTTP/2 frame to server in Node.js

Tags: node.js, http, connection, ping, http2

With the following code:

```
var req = http2.request({
    hostname: 'api.push.apple.com',
    protocol: 'https:',
    port: 443,
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/3/device/' + deviceToken,
    agent: new http2.Agent({log: logger}),
    headers: {
        'apns-topic': 'web.com.example'
    },
    cert: cert,
    key: key,
}, function(res) {
    res.pipe(process.stdout);
});
req.write(JSON.stringify(post));
req.end();
```

how do I send a `PING` frame to check the health of my connection with [node-http2](https://github.com/molnarg/node-http2) module?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ping is a completely different protocol and has nothing to do with HTTP/2

Comment: @FabianBettag - A `ping frame` is an http2 thing that is different than the `ping` program.  See https://http2.github.io/http2-spec/#PING

Comment: I'm sorry then.

Comment: which node version do u use? there is a function `ping` in v8.x.x

Answer (score 0):

From [Node.js HTTP/2 Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http2.html#http2_http2session_ping_payload_callback):

```
session.ping(Buffer.from('12345678'), (err, duration, payload) => {
  if (!err) {
    console.log(`Ping acknowledged in ${duration} milliseconds`);
    console.log(`With payload '${payload.toString()}'`);
  }
});
```